# Can't Initialize Parent Controller from Subfolder in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, routes, controller, codeigniter-4

I have the following structure in CI4 project:

```
app
  pages
    Front.php
    Member.php
  manage
    Courses.php
```

Here are the routing rules:

```
$routes->group('pages', ['namespace' => 'App\Pages'], function ($routes) {
    $routes->resource('member', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);

    $routes->group('manage', ['namespace' => 'App\Pages\Manage'], function ($routes) {
        $routes->resource('courses', ['only' => ['index', 'update']]);
    });
});
```

Front.php is the main controller.

```
namespace App\Pages;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Front extends \CodeIgniter\Controller
{
    protected $me;

    public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger) {
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);
        
        $this->me = $this->run();
        log_message('info', 'My id: ' . $this->me);
        
    }

    private function run() {
        return 10;
    }

    protected function showVal($val) {
        log_message('info', 'Value is: ' . $val);
    }
}
```

Member.php extends Front.php.

```
namespace App\Pages;

class Member extends Front
{
    protected $model;
    public function __construct()
    {
        log_message('info', 'My id in Member: ' . $this->me);
        helper('utils');
        $this->model = model('App\Models\MemberModel');
    }

    public function index() {}
    public function show($mid) {}
}
```

Accessing the URL website.com/pages/member produces the following log message:

> My id: 10

> My id in Member: 10

It means the front controller is properly initialized.

However, I'm failing to initialize the front controller from the subfolder controller.

```
namespace App\Pages\Manage;

use App\Pages\Front;

class Courses extends Front
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        log_message('info', 'My id in Courses: ' . ($this->me ?? 'Not available'));
    }

    public function index() {}
    
    public function update($cid) {
        $this->showVal(100);
    }
}
```

Accessing website.com/pages/manage/courses gives the following log:

> My id in Courses is: not available

However, performing a PUT request on courses gives the log:

> My id in Courses is: not available

> Value is: 100

So the Courses controller is able to include the Front controller but can't get it initialized.

What am I missing?

I'm supposed to let it get initialized in the same manner as the Member controller gets.

Do I need to manually initialize it by calling parent::initController(...) in the courses class constructor?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php __construct() doesn't call parent::__construct() automatically. initController() is also not called by any extending class automatically.

However calling (almost) any function from current instance will call initController(). You do instantiate a model in Member.php's constructor, which forced the shared instance.

A way to secure the initialization is just call initController() in extended constructors.

Comment: I know that the parent class constructor isn't automatically called by the derived class's constructor. However, I thought it should utilize initController(). I have checked by accessing parent class property in the courses function the same as the member.

And yeah. It was populated. Anyway, the model or helper function has no role here in accomplishing the parent in the child's constructor as I tested.

Comment: Solution: In Courses.php

`class Courses extends Front
{
    public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);
    }
}`